# running sql server 2008 on windows 7 and setup its sp problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

I installed sql server 2008 on my windows 7 rtm, but as you see in the screen shot all its services are stop and when i try to start it fail, also when i try to install SP, it give me a big error message.

Is it not possible to install sql 2008 on windows 7 or what should i fix?

feel free to ask me to know more about the problem.

[image]

Comment: Installation and operation problems belong on serverfault, I'd say.

Comment: may be , may be not, really not sure

Comment: Maybe User Access Control is causing a problem?

Comment: @AlexDuggleby i feel that too, but how to solve this issue user access issue? "i am admin on this machine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running Windows 7 and have successfully installed SQL 2008 with no problems.  By the looks of your error, it seems that you may have an aborted/failed previous installation.

You should first check out the setup log files which are usually located at %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log.  Check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx) for help reading the log file.  There may be a clue in there as to why your installation is failing.

You could also check out your server log files in %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG for why the service won't start.

All else fails, you should go to Programs and Features to remove anything that is SQL related and start over.

Comment: I can confirm that SS2008 DOES run on Win7 also. I have it running here.

Comment: can't find any clues which may cause these problems, do you think that removing it and reinstall will solve my problems?

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy: That's the most common suggestion I see for this issue.  Try removing every SQL-related thing.  Then try the install--if it fails, check the logs and do a google or stackoverflow search for the particular problem.